# Additional columns in pyspark GBT Classifier output

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

In the [documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.ml.html#pyspark.ml.classification.GBTClassifier) of gradient boosted trees in pyspark, the inputs/parameters for a `GBTClassifier` object are defined as-

> class pyspark.ml.classification.GBTClassifier( featuresCol='features',
>   labelCol='label',  predictionCol='prediction',  maxDepth=5,
>   maxBins=32, minInstancesPerNode=1,  minInfoGain=0.0,
>   maxMemoryInMB=256, cacheNodeIds=False, checkpointInterval=10, 
>   lossType='logistic', maxIter=20,  stepSize=0.1, seed=None,
>   subsamplingRate=1.0)

there is no `rawPredictionCol` or `probabilityCol` in the arguments while creating the model. And neither does it have a `getRawPredictionCol` or a `getProbabilityCol` method. These methods and arguments are present for the random forest, decision tree, and logistic classifiers

Now, when I fit the model and apply a transform, I get two additional columns by the name of `rawPrediction` and `probability`.

The following is an [example](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.ml.html#pyspark.ml.classification.GBTClassifier) that I used directly from the spark documentation

```
from numpy import allclose
from pyspark.ml.linalg import Vectors
from pyspark.ml.feature import StringIndexer
df = spark.createDataFrame([
    (1.0, Vectors.dense(1.0)),
    (0.0, Vectors.sparse(1, [], []))], ["label", "features"])
stringIndexer = StringIndexer(inputCol="label", outputCol="indexed")
si_model = stringIndexer.fit(df)
td = si_model.transform(df)
gbt = GBTClassifier(maxIter=5, maxDepth=2, labelCol="indexed", seed=42)
model = gbt.fit(td)
model.featureImportances
allclose(model.treeWeights, [1.0, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1])

test0 = spark.createDataFrame([(Vectors.dense(-1.0),)], ["features"])
model.transform(test0).show()
```

The output of the last line from the example is -

```
# +--------+--------------------+--------------------+----------+
# |features|       rawPrediction|         probability|prediction|
# +--------+--------------------+--------------------+----------+
# |  [-1.0]|[1.16967390812510...|[0.91208380260474...|       0.0|
# +--------+--------------------+--------------------+----------+
```

I am confused as to why these columns are present in my output. There is certainly no input parameter because I tried passing `rawPredictionCol = rawPredictions` while calling the class and it throws an error.

Is this a bug? Or is it supposed to output those columns? If those columns are meant to be in the output, then how can I set their names while instantiating the class and why don't they have their respective `get` methods like `getFeaturesCol`, etc

Comment: This is not a bug.  As stated in the [documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/ml-classification-regression.html#gradient-boosted-trees-gbts) returning `rawPrediction` and `probability` is the expected behavior.

Comment: Also, it looks like the the [Scala documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.ml.classification.GBTClassifier) does have parameters where you can set values for these columns, but as of v2.2.1 that functionality hasn't doesn't appear to have been added to PySpark.

Comment: Is there a way I can set the name of the output variables, using something like `setRawPredictionCol()`? Or is there a way I can access the Scala object to set the names?

Comment: I'm not familiar enough with Scala to know if that's possible.  My two cents would be that it's probably a lot more work to access the Scala object through PySpark when you could alternatively use the `alias` function to assign new column names after the `transform` has been called.